# How to disable cache babel/webpack react visual studio

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am working on React application with Asp.Net core from Visual Studio .I have used this tutorial at https://blog.pusher.com/how-to-use-react-with-visual-studio-and-asp-net-web-api/ to get started and the sample application works with babel and webpack. However the changes i make in the jsx file does not seem to reflect on the browser when i run the application .After some research i found that babel caches the data and their website advises to disable it using the following command

BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 babel-node script.js

Here is the link -- https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register/#babel-cache-path

I have no idea on how to do that.This is as far as i went before looking for help : i included the following line inside scripts section in my package.json file hoping it would work.

"start": "BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 babel-node script.js"

But no luck.Any help would be appreciated.Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "1.13.1",
    "babel": "6.5.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.11.1",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.4",
    "babel-core": "6.2.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.2.1",
    "react-dom": "15.2.1"

  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "start": "BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 babel-node script.js"
  },
  "-vs-binding": { "AfterBuild": [ "build" ] }
}
```